# Image doesn't take all it's space inside div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a product view with the product's image, and a heart image inside a `bootstrap container`. I need the image to keep its proportions, while taking as much of the space as it can.

Here are a couple of examples. This one is good:

[image]

And this one is bad, because the image could be larger and still fit inside its div:

[image]

I tried various `CSS` options but this is the best I can get to. Here's my code:

```
<div class="row" align="center" style="border:0px solid green;">                    
   <div align="center" class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-2 galleryproductimg "  style="border:0px solid red; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:0px;">
      <a href='#{product.itemUrl}' target="_blank"> <img id="thumbnailId" src='#{product.thumbnailUrl}' class="img-responsive prodimg" style="border: 0px solid blue; margin-top:0px;" /></a>       
  </div>

  <div align="right" class="col-sx-1 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="border:0px solid black; margin-top:2px; margin-bottom:2px; float:right">     
     <h:commandLink title="Favorite" id="heartImageUnLogged" value="" action="#{mySrchie.paintHeart(product)}"> 
      <h:graphicImage id="heartImageUnLoggedId" library="images" name='#{mySrchie.getHeartImage(product)}' style="display: inline-block;" class="img-responsive"/>
     </h:commandLink>   
  </div>
</div>
```

And the `CSS`:

```
.galleryproductimg {
   max-width: 100%;
   height:110px !important; 
   max-height:110px !important;
}

.prodimg {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 110px;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

What am I missing? How can the image keep its proportions and at the same time take all the space it has?

Answer (score 0):

change your css to this.

```
.prodimg {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 110px;
     max-height: 100%;
     max-width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
```

}

Comment: It looses the proportions like this.

Comment: this is working in my site just try this `height:100%;  width:100%; `

Answer (score 0):

to keep proportions you have to choose if you want to fill the space horizontally or vertically.

horizontally, you just specify the property width:100% :

```
.prodimg {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
}
```

vertically, you just specify the property height:100% :

```
.prodimg {
     position: relative;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Best

Comment: Leaving it as just height:100% or width:100% has the images go outside of their box. It has to be max-height:100% and the problem I have stays the same.

Comment: Do you have either a jsfiddle or a link where we can see it ?